# TwiML loops back to beginning

Tags: twilio-twiml

I have the following TwiML code in Twilio:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Say voice="Polly.Joanna">Thank you for calling.  Please leave a message after the tone.</Say>
<Record transcribe="true" playBeep="true" transcribeCallback="http://twimlets.com/voicemail?Email=example@example.com"/>
  <Say voice="Polly.Joanna">Thank you.</Say>
  <Hangup/>
</Response>
```

When I run it it announces the first Say and then records, but then it loops back again to the first Say and records again.  It never says Thank you or hangs ups.  I get two voicemails emailed to me.

How do I get it to say Thank you and hangup?

Answer (score 0):

If you want anything to happen after the `record` verb, you need to provide an `action` callback URL.
At this `action` callback URL, you'll receive `record` related parameters, and Twilio expects you to provide further TwiML instructions in the response.

> If no action is provided,  will request the current document’s URL.

If you don't provide a URL to the `action` attribute on the `record` verb, then the `action` will be set to the current URL which in your case returns the same TwiML. This is what is causing it to loop forever.

I'm not sure how you are serving your TwiML, but I'll use the [echo Twimlet](https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/echo) here to create a URL for the `action` callback.

So here's your modified TwiML with the `action` attribute, and omitting any verbs after the `record` verb:

```xml
<Response>
  <Say voice="Polly.Joanna">Thank you for calling.  Please leave a message after the tone.</Say>
  <Record action="https://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=%3CResponse%3E%0A%20%20%3CSay%20voice%3D%22Polly.Joanna%22%3EThank%20you.%3C%2FSay%3E%0A%20%20%3CHangup%2F%3E%0A%3C%2FResponse%3E" 
          transcribe="true" 
          playBeep="true" 
          transcribeCallback="https://twimlets.com/voicemail?Email=example@example.com"
  />
</Response>
```

I moved those verbs after the `record` verb into [this echo Twimlet](https://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=%3CResponse%3E%0A%20%20%3CSay%20voice%3D%22Polly.Joanna%22%3EThank%20you.%3C%2FSay%3E%0A%20%20%3CHangup%2F%3E%0A%3C%2FResponse%3E), which returns this TwiML:

```xml
<Response>
  <Say voice="Polly.Joanna">Thank you.</Say>
  <Hangup/>
</Response>
```

As a result, when you are done recording your message, and you stay silent until the `record` verb times out, you'll hear "Thank you." and the call will end. In this case, you don't need the `Hangup` verb I think, but you can use it if you like.

You can read up on [the `action` attribute for the `record` verb in the docs here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record#attributes-action).

Answer (score -1):

Twilio Developer Educator here, I think the problem is you are using a Twimlet in your transcribeCallback, which is itself returning TwiML. The way Twimlets work is they take URL parameters and generate TwiML for you.

If you want to use the email functionality you want to put the Twimlet URL in your incoming call handler and not in the transcriptionCallback attribute.

More info here: https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/voicemail

Hope that helps!

Comment: "Hope that helps!"  It did not help.

Comment: I don't know what a "your incoming call handler" is.  Ultimately I want to code logic that will allow the caller to chose to leave a message or forward to my cell phone.  But for now I just want to leave a voice mail.